# Attempting to implement quicksort in c - sorting structs

Tags: c, unix, sorting, quicksort, struct

Having a little trouble with my quicksort - I'm attempting to pass it & but keep doing something wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The code is implementing a generic quicksort that I found online. Essentially, I'm attempting to copy it but sort by the struct's distance. Therefore if the distance is smaller -  I want to move the two files and sort them appropriately.

Thanks!

```
typedef struct Tag 
{
    char classify;
    float pointX;
    float  pointY;
    float distance;
}PointClassify;

void swap(PointClassify &i, PointClassify &j) 
{
    PointClassify temp;
    temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
}
void quickSort(PointClassify item[], int start, int end)
{
    float pivot;
    int i = start, j = end;

    pivot = item[(start+end)/2].distance;

    while(i <= j)
    {   
            while(item[i].distance < pivot)
            {   
                    i = i+1;
            }   
            while(item[j].distance > pivot)
            {   
                    j = j-1;
            }   
            if(i <= j)
            {   
                    swap(item[i],item[j]);
                    i = i+1;
                    j = j-1;
            }   
     }   
 fprintf(stderr, "This is the number %d \n", item[i].distance);
    if(start < j)
    {   
            quickSort(item, start, j); 
    }   
    if(i < end)
    {   
            quickSort(item, i, end);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Presumably you are doing this for your own edification and not because you didn't notice `qsort` in the standard library?

Comment: In the future it might be helpful to say what problem you are having with your code instead of just saying that you are having a problem.

Comment: I'm attempt to pass swap a & but it's not work. I'm sorry for not making that clearer.

Comment: pass-by-reference is C++

Comment: How is this at all *generic*?

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
void swap(PointClassify &i, PointClassify &j)
```

to this:

```
void swap(PointClassify *i, PointClassify *j)
```

In C, in a declaration, the * indicates that the variable is a pointer to something of that type.  You use the & operator to take the address of a varaible.  You would use it when calling the function, for example:

```
swap(&item[i], &item[j]);
```

Comment: I did as you stated and got a result of; incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct PointClassify *’ from type ‘PointClassify’

Comment: Did you modify the datatype of the temp variable to match that of the function parameters?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The datatype of your swap function's parameters must match the datatype of the temp variable that you declare inside of your swap function in order for you to do the 3 assignments.

Comment: Correct. The parameters are of type "PointClassify *", so the temp variable must also be declared as type "Point Classify *".

Comment: Yes, I've converted this part. It gives me a segmentation error now, but will compile.

Comment: then it's time to load up gdb and start debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it not compile?

pass-by-reference is a C++ feature. Use pointers:

```
swap(PointClassify *i, PointClassify *j)
```

Comment: I've changed it to adapt to swap(PointClassify *i, PointClassify *j) and still get an error.